# How to compare current time to getting time in if condition using android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

i'm creating a scheduling app. In my app, I  need compare to current time to getting time , how to implement in if condition

I don't know how to use it?
 Please help.

Comment: compare to get what time?

Comment: Current time to user can the select time its like getting time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
java.util.Date scheduleTime = ...
...
if (scheduleTime.getTime() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    // do something
}
```